# How to swallow the postback of a asp.net linkbutton control?

Tags: asp.net, html

I have a page with a form containing an  element.  I have the click event being handled client side by a Jscript function, however, the page is still reloading whenever I click the LinkButton, can this be avoided?

aspx

```
<body>
<form>
<asp:LinkButton runat="server" ID="thing" OnClientClick="return SomeFunction()" Text="Some Operation" />
</form>
</body>
```

JScript

```
function SomeFunction() {
    document.getElementById('someText').innerText = 'SomeMessage';
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Can you post your javascript function?

Answer (score 2):

To have the `return false;` working, you will have to add `return` before the Method Name.

ex. `<asp:LinkButtun ID="IDHere" runat="server" OnClientClick="return SomeFunction()" />`

Comment: doesn't seem to resolve the issue, updating the original post with both snippets.

Comment: can you try using the <asp:Button /> I'm pretty sure it works this way. this is how i use it for all Client-Side Validation on Submit Buttons

Comment: I could certainly give that a go, but it would require some serious restyling by my designers.

Comment: I have a good experience with Find-And-Replace, please let me know if you need any further help.

Answer (score 2):

```
SomeButton.Attributes.Add("onclick", "javascript:SomeFunction(); return false;");
```

**Update**: since your updated code is assigned function in ASPX page, you can use this method -

```
<asp:LinkButton runat="server" ID="thing" 
   OnClientClick="javascript:SomeFunction(); return false;" 
   Text="Some Operation" />
```

OR

```
<asp:LinkButton runat="server" ID="thing" 
   OnClientClick="return SomeFunction()" Text="Some Operation" />

function SomeFunction() {
    document.getElementById('someText').innerText = 'SomeMessage';
    return false; /**** Required *****/
}
```

Comment: I have exactly this, but it does not work as advertised, please double check?

Comment: @Firoso `SomeFunction` needs `return false;` explicitly so that it'll cancel the click event. Otherwise, the click event will still post back to server.

Comment: ... Right, which I said it has.  I should update the posts above.

Comment: It tested your code without `document.getElementById('someText').innerText = 'SomeMessage';`, and it works fine. Please note that if you do not have valid dom, you'll have javascript error and it'll still post back.

Comment: The text changes, but it posts back.

Comment: Could you replace `document.getElementById('someText').innerText = 'SomeMessage';` with `alert("clicked"); return false;` and test it again?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/26406/discussion-between-win-and-firoso)